# Can not open gedit on xrdp of ubuntu 16.04 with mstsc on win10

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, xrdp

I have installed xrdp, xubuntu on my ubuntu16.04. It works well when I connect it with win10 by `mstsc`. But I can not open `gedit` with `mstsc`. The error is as following:
`Segmentation fault (core dump)`
And I can not use `firefox` to surf the Internet and other apps to open images. `matlab` works well with GUI. 
It seems that all system built-in GUI apps fails.
What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-xxx/libGLX_nvidia.so.xxx.42 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0
```

replace xxx with your version of the driver